# How to add more than one persistence-unit in persisence.xml?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

Is this proper usage?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="UserBean">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.tugay.registiration.UserBean</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                      value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleapplication"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="CustomerBean">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.tugay.registiration.CustomerBean</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                      value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleapplication"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway since you are writing to the same database, why bother and do not simply add all classes in one?

But if this is what you need. If you want two units in the same file, add `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>` after class tag to exclude those that do not belong this persistence unit. Otherwise persistence A could insert instances of persistence B.

You are better off, in my opinion, having two separate `persistence.xml`. In different folders or with different names.

Bear in mind that you will need two separate `EntityManagers` and `contexts`.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="UserBean">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.tugay.registiration.UserBean</class>
        <class>com.tugay.registiration.CustomerBean</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleapplication"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I add all classes in one? I could not find an example.